# Whats the use of less restrictive member access modifiers than the class access modifier?

Tags: java, oop, access-modifiers

Say I have a class with some members, and the members have a less restrictive access modifier than the class itself.

A concrete example could be:

```java
package apples;

class A { // package private
    public int foo() { // public (=> less restrictive than *package private*)
        return 42;
    }
}
```

To my understanding a ***class*** access modifier that is more restrictive than the ***member*** access modifier, will override the less restrictive ***member*** access modifiers. So a less restrictive ***member*** access modifier should have no effect at all.

- Is my understanding correct?

  - If not, what are the consequences?
- What could be valid reasons to have less restrictive member access modifiers?
- Finally, what are there *best practice* to follow?

---

I also did some experimenting because I thought it might have consequences once I start passing function references around, however even then the access modifier does not seem to matter.

The situation that I constructed is the following:

- `apples.B` provides a public method `bla()` that returns a reference to `apples.A.foo`.
- Then `pizzas.C` calls `apples.B.bla` to obtain a reference to `A.foo` and calls it.
- So `A.foo()` is not directly visible to `C`, but is only indirectly accessible via `B.bla()`

I tested it and it does not make a difference whether I make the access modifier of `foo()` *package private* or not.

```java
package apples;

import java.util.function.IntSupplier;

public class B {
    public IntSupplier getReferenceToAFoo() {
        A aInstance = new A();
        return aInstance::foo;
    }
}
```

```java
package pizzas;

import apples.B;

import java.util.function.IntSupplier;

public class C {
    private int callAFooIndirectly() {
        B bInstance = new B();
        IntSupplier intsupplier = bInstance.getReferenceToAFoo();
        return intsupplier.getAsInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C cInstance = new C();

        int i = cInstance.callAFooIndirectly();
        System.out.println(i);
        assert 42 == i;
    }
}
```

Comment: The most common reason by far for this kind of design is to provide implementations of public API methods (such as those from interfaces or extended abstract classes) using non-public classes. The JDK itself is replete with such classes (ex: `java.util.Collections.SingletonSet<E>` is `private` in `java.util.Collections`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Yes.

> What could be valid reasons to have less restrictive member access modifiers?

Two reasons:

- Sometimes, you're implementing an interface; interface methods must be `public`
- It makes it easier to change the overall access of your class. For instance, if you mark all the methods that you'd ever want to be public `public`, even in a package-private class, then later all you have to do to make the class public is add `public` to the class declaration.

> Finally, what are there best practice to follow?

That's a matter of opinion, so not well-suited to a Stack Overflow question or answer. Do what seems reasonable to you and/or your team, and/or do what your team's style guide tells you to do.